# Number of paths in a grid using backtracking

Tags: algorithm, recursion, backtracking

Given a *square* grid with size *n*, the goal is to find the number of paths from top-left to bottom-right going through *all the squares* in the grid. You are allowed to move in all four directions given that it doesn't intersect with the previously made path. A valid path for n = 7:

[image: A valid path for n = 7]

I plan on using backtracking, for now without any pruning which I'll get into later but I don't understand why my current algorithm isn't working. 
Each node has two attributes: `(bool) taken` and `(vector<Node*>) adj`

```
void paths(Node* start) {
  num_calls++;

  if (path_len == n*n-1) {
    path_count++;
    return;
  }
  else {
    for (Node* neighbour : start->adj) {
      if (!neighbour || neighbour->taken) continue;
      
      start->taken = true;
      path_len++;
      paths(neighbour);

      start->taken = false;
      path_len--;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"?

Comment: for some reason, any value of n i try this on, the recursive calls made are only 5

Comment: Please provide enough information (language? sample data?) to recreate the problem.

Comment: you don't need `vector <Node*> adj`. You just need the index, `i,j`, and then you know the 4 possibilities, `i+1,j`, `i-1,j`, `i,j-1`, `i,j+1`. for each of them, you consult the square and see whether it is taken or not, and do *not* use it if it is already taken. when there is no more possible moves, you check two things: whether you're at `n,n` index, and whether *all* other nodes are `taken`.

Comment: *from top-left to bottom-right* and in your example of the valid path it goes from top left to bottom left..

Answer (score 0):

You should only increment `path_count` in your final condition if the node is indeed the bottom-right corner, i.e. if its coordinates are `n,n` (1-based).

And you should toggle the `taken` attribute of the `neighbour`, not the `start` node:

```cpp
void paths(Node* start) {
  num_calls++;

  if (path_len == n*n-1) {    
    // HERE:
    // if start == n,n:       //     !! NB
    path_count++;
    return;
  }
  else {
    for (Node* neighbour : start->adj) {
      if (!neighbour || neighbour->taken) continue;
      
      neighbour->taken = true;    // was: start->taken = true;
      path_len++;
      paths(neighbour);

      neighbour->taken = false;   // was: start->taken = false;
      path_len--;
    }
  }
}
```

This means that `start->taken` must be `true` from the outset, for the `1,1` starting node.